# OnTriggerEnter doesn't activate although all the requirements are met in Unity 2D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I wrote this simple unity script that is supposed to write in console when it collides with something but it doesn't seem to work.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CollisionScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        Debug.Log("Triggered with " + other.gameObject.name);
    }
}
```

I made sure that both the object that this script is assigned to and the object that this object is supposed to thouch have a RigidBody 2D and a Box Collider 2D and that their Box Colliders have "IsTrigger" activated.

Comment: `OnTriggerEnter` is for and from 3D Physics .. these are different completely unrelated Physics engines ... you want [`OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter2D.html) ... general tip: Usually if something doesn't happen that needs certain requirements - then **not** `all the requirements are met` ;)

Comment: A bit of advice for asking questions if you don't want to decrease your reputation. Firstly, search the web, In this case, "OnTriggerEnter in Unity 2d". Secondly, search for tutorials on Youtube, Last but not least, consider asking ChatGPT about the problem and give it your code. If it still doesn't help, then ask on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Your script uses [OnTriggerEnter](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html), which is correct for 3D projects, but because you're working in 2D, you need to use [OnTriggerEnter2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter2D.html) as follows:

```c
using UnityEngine;

public class CollisionScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        Debug.Log("Triggered with " + other.gameObject.name);
    }
}
```

Comment: The passed-in type should be `Collider2D`.

Comment: It just goes to show how easy it is to switch up 3D and 2D when you get used to it  Amended in an edit, thank you!